Cannot install many programs successfully with `snap`
After successfully installing the latest Ubuntu Linux, I am having issues installing more programs, e.g. VS Codium and more.
This is what happens:
> sudo snap install codium --classic
snap "codium" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
> /snap/bin/codium

Nothing happens when I launch the installed program. I just get the prompt back after a fraction of a second. No error messages.
> ll /snap/bin/codium
lrwxrwxrwx 1 13 2024-06-13 11:37 /snap/bin/codium -> /usr/bin/snap*

The file is a link to a common snap file.
I make a search for "codium" of my whole system, and I find a few more interesting files:
/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/codium
/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/bin/codium

None of them works.
This is what I get from the type and readlink commands:
> type -a codium
codium is /snap/bin/codium
> readlink -f $(which codium)
/usr/bin/snap

What does this mean? Is it a bug or am I doing anything wrong?
Thank you.
OS: Ubuntu Linux 24.04

Running codium in verbose mode I get plenty of interesting info:
~> codium --verbose
Gtk-Message: 15:49:25.662: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
[153343:0614/154925.672591:ERROR:proxy_config_service_linux.cc(620)] inotify_init failed: Too many open files (24)
[153343:0614/154925.672752:ERROR:file_path_watcher_inotify.cc(315)] inotify_init() failed: Too many open files (24)
[153343:0614/154925.695972:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[153372:0614/154925.715262:ERROR:file_path_watcher_inotify.cc(315)] inotify_init() failed: Too many open files (24)
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
...
[153365:0614/154925.788326:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(196)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.787Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  merge: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  'pre-release': false,
  'update-extensions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'disable-chromium-sandbox': false,
  sandbox: false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  'enable-smoke-test-driver': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'use-inmemory-secretstorage': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'preserve-env': false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  'disable-gpu-sandbox': false,
  '__enable-file-policy': false,
  'enable-coi': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  'disable-dev-shm-usage': false,
  'profile-temp': false,
  logsPath: '/home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/logs/20240614T154925'
}
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.788Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.789Z] Resolved machine identifier: 5d824ba39346432401d759b3964a6149554e3b747050fb1498b8010fd55e2862
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.789Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.797Z] StorageMainService: creating application storage
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.798Z] update#setState idle
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.799Z] Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/snap/codium'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/original-fs/watchers:247:19)
    at watch (node:original-fs:2418:34)
    at new g (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:109:56471)
    at b._createInstance (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:2092)
    at b._createServiceInstance (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:5374)
    at b._createServiceInstanceWithOwner (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:4226)
    at b._createAndCacheServiceInstance (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:3894)
    at b._safeCreateAndCacheServiceInstance (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:3035)
    at b._getOrCreateServiceInstance (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:2756)
    at Object.get (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:1129)
    at ft.initChannels (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:110:86205)
    at /snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:110:73357
    at b.invokeFunction (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:999)
    at ft.startup (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:110:73333)
    at async Ee.startup (/snap/codium/394/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:112:1436)
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] Lifecycle#kill()
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - begin 'instanceLockfile'
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] storageMainService#onWillShutdown()
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - begin 'applicationStorage'
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] StorageMainService: closed application storage
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.800Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - end 'applicationStorage'
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.801Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - end 'instanceLockfile'
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.801Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Failed to watch /home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User for changes using fs.watch() (Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User')
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.802Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to stop watching: /home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>),/home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>)
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.802Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] stopping file watcher (/home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>))
[main 2024-06-14T14:49:25.802Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] stopping file watcher (/home/pietrom/.config/VSCodium/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>))


Have you checked the common issues listed on this Snap support page? Is you home directory the usual /home/<username> or something else? If you run sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1, will codium work then?

@telcoM - Yes, my home is /home/<username>. What is the effect of the command you propose? It is a runtime configuration of a kernel parameter, but it looks like a generic setting, not specific to codium...

If codium uses sandboxing technology (like Teams and Chromium -based apps), it requires access to a kernel feature called user namespaces. The feature used to be restricted to root only, but newer kernels and distributions consider it matured enough for use by regular users. If Ubuntu still has that restriction in effect, this should relax it and allow use of user namespaces by non-root users. Having this restriction in place is known to cause sandboxing apps to exit without error, as mentioned in the page I linked. The command I described is non-persistent: effect will go away on reboot.

If the sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1 allows the application to work, then we'll have an idea of why it might be exiting without an error message. If the sysctl command returns an error, run cat /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces: if it outputs a value of zero, a similar restriction is implemented in a newer way.

@telcoM - I realised I have an issue with my /var directory/partition, which may be the cause of this problem. I opened another question in this regard.
